# Переход с одного на другой спрайты из массива

Tags: android, java

Добрый день всем. Пишу игру на android, возник вопрос как сделать переход по массиву, пытался сделать так создал массив с картинками:

```
/**Массив размеров квадрата*/
    private Bitmap[] masPlayer = new Bitmap[] { BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.player_0),
            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.player_1),
            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.player_2),
            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.player_3),
            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.player_4),
            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.player_5),
            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.player_6),
            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.player_7),
            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.player_max)};
```

Вызываю в конструкторе его:

```
player = masPlayer[sizeRect];
p = new Player(this, player);
```

И при столкновении делаю переход на следующий квадрат:

```
player = masPlayer[sizeRect++];
```

Но ничего не происходит, как можно сделать переход с одного на другой?

player - это bitmap. 
p - объект класса Player. 
sizeRect = 1;

**UPDATE:**

Для того что бы все работало, нужно написать так:

> player = masPlayer[sizeRect++];
>     p.bmp = player;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо написать:

```
player = masPlayer[++sizeRect];
```

тогда `player` получит значение `masPlayer[sizeRect+1]`, а в вашей версии получает значение `masPlayer[sizeRect]` - прочитайте документацию об отличиях между постфиксным и префиксными операторами инкремента

Comment: К сожалению ничего не изменилось. Есть другие версии?